# how to hide a column while displaying in Gridview after binding datasource to gridview

Tags: vb.net

Want to display dataTable in GridView and hide one of the columns but not Delete the column

i have code like this

```
dataGrid1.AllowSorting = True
    dataGrid1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0).DefaultView
    dataGrid1.CurrentPageIndex = 0
    dataGrid1.DataBind()
    dataGrid1.Visible = True
    dataSet = Nothing
```

dataSet looks like this

Name  Number   Address
xxx   xxx      xxxx

I want to display like this
Name  Address
xxx   xxxx

and then i will add original dataGrid(before hiding column) version to Session to use it another place.

please help me with the code to hide column without deleting the column.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [DataControlField.Visible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfield.visible?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. 
Added below code in styles file and i am getting what i want.

`#dataGrid1 div:nth-child(n+2) td:nth-child(7) {
    display: none;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You are able to hide a column by

`dgvGridView.Columns(0).Visible = False`

and still keep/write the data into it.

Comment: [GridView Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview). From `System.Web.UI.WebControls`.

Comment: @MHammer I did tried this line of code but it is redirecting to error page while the `DataGrid` is loading data into it! when i debug it, i see count for the `Columns` is 0.

Comment: @CodeMonkey: Are you certain that there is data in the `Datagrid`? If it returns with an error that `Columns(0)` is out of `index` it seems that it has no data.

Comment: @MHammer: Yes I am 100% that there is data in the `DataGrid`. I can display the data in `gridview` wothout an issue. But, if i want to use `dgvGridView.Columns(0).Visible = False` I am seeing `Columns(0)` and i can still see data in `gridview` without hiding the Column that i want to hide. I tried Deleting the Column I want to hide but as i said before I am using the `DataGrid`(retreving data for the selected row when by selecting it. the main Column I am using to this process is the same column that i want to Hide). Does it make sense?

Comment: Just a dumb question: Are you inputting `dgvGridView.Columns(0).Visible = False` or `dataGrid1.Columns(0).Visible = False` ?

As of you code above in you thread, I am certain that you need to use the last one: `dataGrid1.Columns(0).Visible = False` so it has reference to the dgv you've used.